# Experience Optimization 8.1.1 Installation issue

Tags: experience-optimization, web8

On the Experience Optimization installation media, I navigate to the folder Content Manager and double-click Install SDL Web Experience Optimization. Installation completed successfully and after machine Reboot I am not able to see any Template Building Block called "Add to Experience Optimization". Please let me know if I am missing something. I followed the steps mentioned in sdl documentation http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-0A26A886-0DC2-4889-A939-CB07E8C5BA43#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-F717D17C-F85F-4D01-BCF2-9FA98F40655B.xml&docid=GUID-F717D17C-F85F-4D01-BCF2-9FA98F40655B&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-F717D17C-F85F-4D01-BCF2-9FA98F40655B

Answer (score 4):

The XO installer doesn't add XO TBBs to existing Publications. It does add the XO TBBs to the set of templates to create for new Publications (BluePrint roots).

If you want to get the XO TBBs in an existing BluePrint, you have to use the SDL Template Builder to Create/update Default Templates in your BluePrint root Publication.